# Any potential problem with using std::is_same_v rather than overload or specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

For example, I've got this:

```
// Code A
int create_int() { return 42; }
double create_double() { return 3.14; }
std::string create_string() { return {"Hi"}; }
```

Now let's assume that it makes sense to put these `create`s together, so I rewrite the code:

```
// Code B
template <typename T> T create();
template <> int create<int>() { return 42; }
template <> double create<double>() { return 3.14; }
template <> std::string create<std::string>() { return {"Hi"}; }
```

Or even:

```
// Code C
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> T create()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    {
        return 42;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
    {
        return 3.14;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        return {"Hi"};
    }
    else
    {
        // static_assert(false);
        return static_cast<T>(0);
    }
}
```

I wanna to know is there any difference between these codes, or is it just about code style.

Comment: I guess you mean "_overload_ or specialization"

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Yeah, thanks.

Comment: Overload is different, since it can convert types. Also overload cannot be applied here, it is not possible to overload by return type only. But regarding `if constexpr` vs specialization I'm not sure. `if constexpr` is rather new thing.

Comment: the big difference is that `if constexpr` is available only starting from C++17. Before C++17 you have to use different `create()` specializations.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev You got me again. Actually in my real-world-problem it is reasonable to overload functions since there are parameters, I just forgot it here.

Answer (score 1):

There are semantic differences between these. You can't use the `Code A` functions in generic algorithms like in this example:

```
template <class T>
T generic_function() {
    return create<T>();
}
```

Therefore I would prefere Code B over Code A.

The constexpr if is useful if you need to take a different route in generic algorithms. It saves you from creating an overloaded helper function or worse constructs.

An example would be to take a different route for `void` over other datatypes because you can not pass `void` as a parameter to a function. Suppose you take a function and want to set the value of a `std::promise` to the result. This function might not return a value, but you still want to execute the function. In this case the `constexpr if` will save you from a lot of headache and template metaprogramming.

```
template <class Fn>
void my_function(Fn fn) {
    std::promise<decltype(fn())> promise;

    if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<void, decltype(fn())>) {
        promise.set_value(fn());
    } else {
        fn();
        promise.set_value();
    }
}
```